# Labels not rendered at all scales of map composer, QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, labeling

Like the title states, my labels aren't rendered at all scales of the map composer. This makes it very difficult to move and position them since I can't always see where they are.

Exporting the map after bringing it into the print layout has all the labels rendered, so they're there, they just aren't showing up for me to preview.

Render options has scale dependent and pixel-based visibility off, show all labels on, discourage labels from covering features off.

This issue only occurs at a non-zero rotations. At zero rotation, I can see and move labels fine at all scales.

E.g of issue.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

First image at 1:5838303, second at 1:2919152.

So is there a way to enable label visibility in the composer at all scales?